# Map-reduce : work on multiple lines

Tags: mapreduce, mapper

I have a requirement where i need to work on multiple rows of input data, first sort the data and then substract one value from row one in next row and so on. Can we do this operation in map reduce somehow ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make your **custom Record Reader** and send your desired number of records to map task and perform the calculations.